# How to include ag-grid styles for Angular 5?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I'm using Angular 5 with ag-grid 17.x and am just trying to do a simple, "hello world"-type example, but having trouble getting the grid to display appropriately.  I have the following HTML in my template:

```
<div style="width: 800px; height: 500px" class="ag-theme-balham">
  <ag-grid-angular
                   [rowData]="rowData"
                   [columnDefs]="columnDefs">
  </ag-grid-angular>
</div>
```

...and I don't get any errors, but instead of a grid, it's just rendered as one jumbled column of text.

Anyway, I noticed in dev tools that the styles that the grid was pointing to weren't there, so I imported them in the .angular-cli.json:

```
  "styles": [
    "scss/styles.scss",
    "../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css",
    "../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-theme-balhom.css"
  ],
```

...and this worked, but the solution doesn't seem right to me.  I tried to import them in one of my .scss files:

```
@import '~ag-grid/src/styles/ag-grid.scss';
@import '~ag-grid/src/styles/ag-theme-fresh.scss';
```

...but got a bunch of reference errors (couldn't find icons, etc.).

My question is how should ag-grid styles and themes be imported into an Angular application?  I've dug around in the documentation, but can't seem to find the solution that I stumbled upon, so assume it's wrong...but can't find anything that works either.  Thanks for any help![image]

Comment: please refer to this documentation - https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-angular-angularcli/ , you need to add the style sheets for ag-grid in angular-cli.json file

Comment: Thank you! Somehow missed that document.

Comment: you also mistyped balhom, it should be balham

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link @koolhuman has provided is correct, I would like to add two points on top of that.

1. You should keep your `styles.scss` file reference at the last in `styles` array in `.angular-cli.json` file. The ag-grid styles you want to override will be overridden if you keep `styles.scss` before `ag-grid` styles.
2. Add `class="ag-theme-balhom"` or `class="ag-theme-fresh"` on you `<ag-grid-angular>` element. *In short, whichever theme you want to apply.*